# Draw multiple pie chart vertically?

Tags: delphi, teechart

With default settings I have a result like this:
[image]

Q: Is there any way to draw multiple pie chart vertically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the example at "All features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Standard\Pie\Multiple Pies" in the features demo shipped with TeeChart installation (or download the precompiled demo [here](https://www.steema.com/download/vcl))

In it, you'll see how you can define the rectangle to be used by a series, at the series'  `BeforeDrawValues` event. Ie:

```
procedure TPieMultiple.Series1BeforeDrawValues(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.ChartRect:=Rect(10,10,Chart1.Width div 2, Chart1.Height div 2);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I can't find `OnBeforeDrawValues` event. There is no design time event like that and also Chart1.SeriesList.Items[1] doesn't has such an event.

Comment: OK, got it. I must use `Chart2.SeriesList.Items[0].BeforeDrawValues:= MyProcedure;`. Actually it's name is `BeforeDrawValues`.

Comment: Right, sorry. I've modified the answer